# Loading time Delphi XE2 application

Tags: performance, delphi, debugging, delphi-xe2, release

I have a strange behavior with the loading time of an application written in Dephi XE2. I compiled the same source in debug mode and release mode. Both .exe reside on the same machine, same hard disk, same... everything, only the folder is different.

When I run the application in debug mode (45MB), it takes around 6 seconds to load and around 50 seconds to load the application compiled in release mode (15MB).

How this can be ? What do you recommend to check in order to improve the performance in release mode ?

Comment: One place to start looking might be your OS path.

Comment: OK, I have just moved the .exe file, release version, in a brand new folder on the same hard disk. In this new folder there is only the .exe file and here it takes 7 seconds. Why is it ?

Comment: @MartynA What do you mean for OS path ? I have Win 7

Comment: "Why is it ?"  Did you reboot to avoid caching effects?  If you did, then maybe you need a utility which tells you which DLLs get loaded preparatory to your Exe and where the OS found them.  Another thing you might try is to trace your Exe's units' initialization sections and see whether it behaves differently depending on what folder your Exe is in.

Comment: "What do you mean for OS path?"  Sorry, I meant the folders listed in your system's Path environment variable.  Type "SET > dump.txt & notepad dump.txt" at a command prompt to inspect it.  Windows uses it as part of its algorithm for locating/loading DLLs your Exe depends on.

Comment: I haven't rebooted yet but I will do and will let you know. The .exe has no dependency on the folder name; behavior is the same no matter the folder. Do you mean the .exe compiled in debug mode is linked to some DLLs and the one in release mode is linked to other DLLs that may not be in the path ? However I renamed the .exe debug mode and moved to the folder where the .exe release is. No change, the .exe debug is still significantly faster than the release version.

Comment: I just checked the OS path. None of the folders are in the path

Comment: "Do you mean the .exe compiled " No, but if your Exe depends on some DLL which is present in your debug folders but not the other one, that might make a difference. "behavior is the same ..." - but you said it changed when you moved it.  Btw, SO is telling me that this is getting too much like chat, so I'll leave it there.

Comment: Do you use conditionals which compile different code for Debug / Release? That's the only reason I could imagine other than the obvious settings.

Comment: This question asks us to tell you what your program does during startup. We don't know. We don't have your program. You do. You need to do some debugging and profiling. We cannot do that for you.

Comment: @MartynA You are looking for differences between the two executable startups. The PATH variable is global and shared. So it's not a candidate.